# Update control text while process is running

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to change the button text while a server-side process runs, and then change text after finishing. The following code does not work; I'm assuming due to it possibly running synchronously?? Is this achievable?

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    btnUpdate.Text = "Updating"

    Dim myProcess As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path to file")

    myProcess.WaitForExit()

    btnUpdate.Text = "Update"

    myProcess.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a bit more complex than you think.  First you need to understand how HTTP works.  Specifically, there is *one* request to the server and *one* response from the server.  So the server has to finish its work entirely before sending the response to the client.  To get periodic updates, you'll need to use AJAX and probably something like Web Sockets (look into something called SignalR).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I was able to accomplish what I needed by creating a click event handler that updated the text on the client-side. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button text as soon as it is clicked, with `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClientClick="this.value = 'Updating';" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

It should get back to its original value when the page is refreshed after the postback.